# Using 4-SUM to improve Subset Sum $O(2^{n/2})$ runtime

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

I read k-Sum $k \geq 3$ can be solved in $\approx O(n^{k/2})$

If this is right, why do not have a subset sum solver with a time complexity $O(2^{n/4})$ or better?

That is, enumerating all the subsets from 4 splits, then apply 4-sum to find if some of the four partial lists add up to the target value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Work through the math; you are off by a factor of two.  Also, you might be confusing yourself by using the same letter $n$ for two different things.

Suppose we have a list of $N$ numbers.  You are proposing to split that into four chunks, where each chunk has $N/4$ numbers.  Enumerating all of the subsets of a single chunk takes $O(2^{N/4})$ time.  Now, you have a 4-sum problem where you are working 4 lists each containing $M=2^{N/4}$ items.  This 4-sum problem can be solved in $O(M^{k/2}) = O(M^{4/2}) = O(M^2)$, and $M^2 = 2^{N/2}$, so your proposed algorithm runs in $O(2^{N/2})$ time.

There *is* an algorithm for subset-sum that runs in time $O(2^{N/2})$ and space $O(2^{N/4})$.  The algorithm is due to Schroeppel and Shamir.  However, it's running time is still $O(2^{N/2})$, not $O(2^{N/4})$.

I don't think there is any known subset-sum algorithm whose running time is non-trivially better than $O(2^{N/2})$.  Blum, Kalai, and Wasserman have solved a related problem in subexponential time, but it's a different problem.

Comment: will $O(\frac{2^{n/2}}{sqrt(n)})$ considered trivial?

Comment: @JesusSalas, good question, I don't know!

Comment: Good answer! I love it, in fact, I like very much how you handle the stuff in the forum, I always look up your answers. So I have to ask, would be much to ask if you can take a look/review a draft? (as a sanity check I'm not clouding my own judgment!), I can't/don't' want is as good as a yes, whatever works for you.

Comment: @JesusSalas, Cool.  If you have a URL you can share I will take a look if I can get a chance (but no promises).  If it's private I unfortunately won't be able help at this stage.

Comment: I get the deal as is, let me get it ready, and if you do not find the time... no problem at all, I appreciate the intention anyways!

Comment: ...3 years later..., @D.W. if you offer is still in place (no promises included) I will share the draft with you, there was much than I expected and took a bit to get everything together...

Comment: @JesusSalas, I confess I probably won't have time to look at it now -- my apologies.  Congratulations on finishing the work!

Comment: I did not know.. I understand now and I am so humbled, have no words, thanks from the bottom of my hearth for supporting all of us, I know for sure I do not deserve it, I want to apology if I have been a persistent annoyance to you. Let me try to compensate with the only thing of any possible value I have. To let you be the first to know about my results... 3 years ago I was able to remove the lists scan step for SSP in the classical algorithm from Horowitz and Sahni (what followed after this is still amazing me). Again, thank you, and please consider this thread closed forever!